# MS Access Date() Function and SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I cant seem to find a straight answer to what seems is common scenario. I recently converted an access db to SQL Server, and have linked tables (odbc). Since dates are now being stored as in datetime2 as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, i have had no problem in VBA to have my forms write to the database like `Format(VBA.Date, "yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00")`.

However I have a few simple queries in Access that had a where clause like:

```
Where Field = Date()
```

and also

```
Where Field Between Date() And Date()-7
```

What is the proper way to query these from an Access query to SQL server?

Comment: BETWEEN arguments must be listed from smallest to largest. [Not that you should be using BETWEEN for range queries anyway](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your Access Code**

```
Where Field = Date()
```

**Sql Server**

```
Where Field = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Function <kbd>[GETDATE()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)</kbd> gets the current Datetime.

**Date between today and last 7 days**

```
Where Field BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AS DATE) 
                     AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

The reason I have used `CAST()` function is because `GETDATE()` returns the current Datetime something like this `2014-02-09 22:09:53.067`

now if you are checking values WHERE Field has the today's date it will only the the values `where Field = '2014-02-09 22:09:53.067'` Not the records where Date `2014-02-09` it will also take the time into consideration there for I used the CAST Function to get rid of the time part from GETDATE() function.

```
SELECT GETDATE()  Returns '2014-02-09 22:09:53.067'

SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) Returns '2014-02-09'
```

I have fixed the issues with your query there were quite a few of them :S I would suggest reading books online and learn the correct synatx for sql server , see below the fixed query

```
SELECT TransactionTotals.[Date]
    , TransactionTotals.EntryID
    , TransactionItems.ItemID
    , TransactionItems.ClientID
    , [FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName] AS Name
    , TransactionItems.[Service]
    , TransactionItems.Therapist
    , TransactionItems.GiftCertificate
    , TransactionItems.Charge
    , TransactionItems.Gratuity
    , TransactionTotals.Paid
    , TransactionItems.Comments 

FROM   CLIENTS INNER JOIN TransactionItems
ON     CLIENTS.ClientID = TransactionItems.ClientID 
INNER JOIN TransactionTotals
ON     TransactionTotals.EntryID = TransactionItems.EntryID
WHERE  TransactionTotals.[Date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
ORDER BY TransactionTotals.EntryID DESC;
```

Comment: WHERE TransactionTotals.Date=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) gets 'Syntax Error (missing operator)

Comment: @user1457613 Post the full query in your question.

Comment: Your this bit of query is correct there is something else somewhere else you are missing

Comment: Well, its the only line being changed but:

Comment: SELECT TransactionTotals.Date, TransactionTotals.EntryID, TransactionItems.ItemID, TransactionItems.ClientID, ([FirstName] & " " & [LastName]) AS Name, TransactionItems.Service, TransactionItems.Therapist, TransactionItems.GiftCertificate, TransactionItems.Charge, TransactionItems.Gratuity, TransactionTotals.Paid, TransactionItems.Comments
FROM CLIENTS INNER JOIN (TransactionTotals INNER JOIN TransactionItems ON TransactionTotals.EntryID = TransactionItems.EntryID) ON CLIENTS.ClientID = TransactionItems.ClientID

Comment: WHERE TransactionTotals.Date=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
ORDER BY TransactionTotals.EntryID DESC;

Comment: Thank You for that. I will mark your original answer as correct in a minute. I still get syntax errors when trying to view the queries in Access. When I run the queries in SQL Management Studio, they run fine. Obviously a problem with Access interpretation in query/SQL design mode. I still just need to use Access as a front end on this tranasaction database until i build new .NET application forms to do so.

Comment: Posted a follow up question to try solve issue why doesn't work in Access.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666841/ms-access-sql-server-db-query-syntax-for-cast-function

Comment: Why not continue to use a linked table, and build the query in the access client. That way, your existing access sql will not have to be change. There is really no reason in "most" cases to convert the access queries to sql server. Your existing sql queries in Access should continue to run fine, and they only pull records requested - not the whole table.  You can certainly over time convert sql to t-sql (server side), but for most access queries, they will continue to run fine and you don't need nor want to re-write them unless they are complex, or running slow on the client.