# MS Access SQL Server DB - Query Syntax for CAST Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2007

I have converted an Access db (.mdb) to SQL Server. In the meantime I still need to use Access as a front end until new application forms are constructed. Can someone tell me what I might do to fix the situation where:

In Access 2007, a query such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM TransactionTotals
WHERE TransactionTotals.[Date]= Date()
ORDER BY TransactionTotals.EntryID DESC;
```

worked, however since the Date() function will not work with SQL Server, with help in a previous post the correct syntax is:

```
SELECT *
FROM TransactionTotals
WHERE TransactionTotals.[Date]= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
ORDER BY TransactionTotals.EntryID DESC;
```

BUT! Although the code above will work in a direct SQL Server query (SQL Management Studio), it will be tossed out in Access with a Syntax Error response on the WHERE clause.

Can something be done in Access so I can still run my query bound forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do exactly what you do, Access first before migration to SQL server. Access has some really weird syntax compared to server type databases especially when it comes to JOIN clauses and dates, GETDATE() only works on SQL Server, in Access, try this...

```
SELECT *
FROM TransactionTotals
WHERE TransactionTotals.[Date]= Format(NOW(),"General Date")
ORDER BY TransactionTotals.EntryID DESC;
```

Feel free to change the format of the date, with or without time.

Comment: That works agains SQL Server from Acces as: Format(NOW(),"yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00"). However, what may work in a Access query such as WHERE TransactionTotals.[Date] Between Date()-7 AND Date()

Comment: Uhmmm, Can you explain a bit more about what you need? From what I understood, you need to query against a database with a condition comparing the current date, and your SQL statement that works on SQL Server doesn't work on Access right? Are you trying to find a function that works on both?

Comment: Access (.mdb) recently converted MDB to SQL Server - date fields in datetime2. Linked tables (odbc) Just trying to get a couple of Access query bound forms to still pull records from the SQL Server, until  can build new .NET application.

Comment: So your current SQL statement does not work on Access right? And you're trying to convert the statement to something that's SQL server friendly?

Comment: What problem do you see when using my suggested SQL statement above?

Comment: Yes. My Date fields in SQL Server are stored as yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00. Your statement did not work in Access against the SQL Server db with "General Date" but does work as Format(NOW(),"yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00"). I am looking also for good language for a similar Access query: Between Date() And Date()-7

Comment: Ahhh yes, The 'General Date' format was just an example, it's a format for Access since you said GETDATE() did not work. It's the reason why I stated feel free to change the format of the date :) The closest thing to Access in terms of syntax is SQL Server because SQL Server and Access are both products from Microsoft, although all SQL Servers generally have the same syntax. So it's technically impossible to migrate to a server type database from Access without changing anything, unless the SQL statements you used are rock bottom basics, no conditions, no additional clauses.